# Is there a name for a formula to calculate ascending numbers to a quadratic-like sequence?

Tags: javascript, numbers

For e.g. any range of number 0 - n

> [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]

to:

> [ 0, 2, 4, 6, 4, 2, 0 ]

IS there a formula to calculate the first into the second? Quadratic?
Is there a name for this kind of formula or calculation?

EDIT: This should be in Javascript

Comment: I have no idea how you've gone from the first sequence to the second sequence.

Comment: Where's the code?  What Language?

Comment: I wanted to calculate this using javascript

Comment: Given the absence of an attempted algorithm, this is off topic. If you can edit this to show an actual programming problem, please flag it for moderator attention to be reviewed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "quadratic-like" but the following javascript program prints something which looks like your sequence:

```
n = 6;
for(i=0;i<=n;i++){
  print(i, n-Math.abs(2*i-n))
}
```

Output:

```
0 0
1 2
2 4
3 6
4 4
5 2
6 0
```

Comment: Holy crap - what is that sequence called? (And, how did you recognize it?)

Comment: @KevinDTimm I don't know if it has any name. I would call it "triangle over zero to n".

Comment: That's only descriptive, maybe name it "Howard's Algorithm"?

Comment: that is, well in my opinion, genius.